# Exporting iOS vCards without resizing images

Tags: resize, addressbook, thumbnails, vcf-vcard

My iPhone app is currently backing up users' contacts to .vcf files using the method ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople of AddressBook framework.

But this method shrinks the images of the contacts, and I would like to have the option to keep them in original size.

What better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Still keep on getting all the vcards through `ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople` and keep them in an `NSDictionary` where the key is the person's ID and the value is the vCard
2. Go through all the people in the address book and get the image data using `ABPersonCopyImageData` and save that in an `NSDictionary` where the key is the person's ID and the value is the base64 string representation of the image data.
3. Go through the first `NSDictionary` and replace the base64 encoding (that long series of characters in the `PHOTO` tag) with the value for that person's ID in the second dictionary.
4. Use the first dictionary's values in whatever you want, because now, the values should contain vCards with original sized pictures.